# Greek language is not used in Android

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I want to support the greek language.

I translated my `string.xml` into the greek language.

Then I put the greek `string.xml` it into a folder called: `res/values-gr` besides the normal `res/values`.

So my folder looks like this: `res/values-gr/string.xml`

Then I set my phone language to greek.

However, the app still displays english only.

Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to create a folder:

- `values-el` for the Greek translation, or
- `values-el-rGR` for the country-specific Greek translation.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for this. I couldn't find this info anywhere.